# How to introduce a delay before reloading an Angular project when the associated library is recompiled?

Tags: angular, webpack

I am working on an **Angular** project that depends on a custom library I've built. I am using the `--watch` option to automatically recompile my library whenever I make a change.

However, I've noticed that occasionally, when my library gets recompiled, my main project crashes or encounters errors, likely because it's trying to access the library while it's being recompiled.

My current workflow involves running two separate commands in two different terminals. In the first terminal, I kick off the `ng mylib:build --watch` for my library. In the second terminal, I start my main project with `npm start`.

I am looking for a solution that would allow me to introduce a delay before my main project gets reloaded whenever my library is recompiled. This way, I could ensure that the library's recompilation is completely finished before the main project attempts to import it again.

I have looked into options in the Angular and Webpack documentation, but I couldn't find a solution for this specific issue. I've also considered using nodemon to watch for changes in my library and restart my main application, but I'm not sure how I could introduce a delay in this process.

Has anyone encountered this issue and could help me find a solution?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You'll probably need to tweak the tsconfig of your project to use the src instead of the dist from the library, at least in serve mode.

Comment: I found a solution ! Thank you @maxime1992

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with the help of `@maxime1992`.
I modified my TypeScript configuration so that it points to the `src` of my library during development, instead of the `dist`.
To achieve this, I created a separate TypeScript configuration file for development, named `tsconfig.dev.json`, which extends my existing tsconfig.app.json and overrides the `paths` configuration.

Here's the configuration I used for `tsconfig.dev.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "my-library": ["projects/my-library/src/public-api"]
    }
  }
}
```

In this way, it's as if the library was part of the main project. And so, it gets compiled with it.

I then created a development mode to use when I'm developing in the library.

I added a `development` configuration in my `angular.json` file for build & serve:

```json
"projects": {
  "my-app": {
    ...
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
        "options": {
          ...
          "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
          ...
        },
        "configurations": {
          "production": {
            ...
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.prod.json"
            ...
          },
          "development": {
            ...
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.dev.json"
            ...
          }
        }
      },
      "serve": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
        "options": {
          ...
          "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
        },
        "configurations": {
          "production": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production"
          },
          "development": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build:development"
          }
        }
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "ng serve --configuration development --port 4292",
    "start": "ng serve"
  }
}
```

You just then need to run `npm run start:dev`